# How to determine the RAM Size of my MongoDB Server

Tags: mongodb

I have used the command

```
db.collection.stats()

db.stats()
{
        "collections" : 17,
        "objects" : 487747,
        "avgObjSize" : 1924.9327048654322,
        "dataSize" : 938880152,
        "storageSize" : 1159314432,
        "numExtents" : 82,
        "indexes" : 32,
        "indexSize" : 153812992,
        "fileSize" : 8519680000,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

From net i found out this statement

**Indexes should always be in memory .(which is nothing but RAM)**

The index size is `153812992` and the datasize is `938880152`

Could you please tell me what amount of RAM do i require on my MongoDB  server , so that the performance is aways great .

As per the applciation design , daiily nearly 100k insertions/updations might happen , And one more question i have is , does this index size will grow each day ??

Then in that case how can i determine the best fit RAM Size for my Application .

please advice , thanks in advance .

Comment: You working set is what's important

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a tool in the later versions of MongoDB to help with finding out how big your working set is, it is still quite experimental but it should work: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#serverStatus.workingSet

The best way to use this is simply to make a automated test script which will use your application and in the meantime print out `serverStatus` and archive the value of the working set document. You can graph it, etc etc and come to a reasonable conclusion of what your RAM needs to be.

Comment: Changed in version 3.0: The server status output no longer includes the workingSet

Does anyone know a solution for 3.0?

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan I guess you manually have to do it again with mongostat and logging for a time interval

Answer (score 7):

Somethings are changed in years about MongoDB. 
Today MongoDB says that:

> Changed in version 3.0: `serverStatus` no longer outputs the `workingSet`

TL;DR

If MMAPv1 storage engine is used on MongoDB concerning of `working set` is **present**.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#must-my-working-set-size-fit-ram

If WiredTiger storage engine is used on MongoDB, **not need to think about `working set`**.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#memory-diagnostics-for-the-wiredtiger-storage-engine

> ## Memory Diagnostics for the WiredTiger Storage Engine
>
> **Must my working set size fit RAM?**
>
> No.
>
> **How do I calculate how much RAM I need for my application?**
>
> With WiredTiger, MongoDB utilizes both the WiredTiger internal cache
>   and the filesystem cache.
>
> Changed in version 3.2: Starting in MongoDB 3.2, the WiredTiger
>   internal cache, by default, will use the larger of either:
>
> 60% of RAM minus 1 GB, or 1 GB.

**Update**

> Starting in 3.4, the WiredTiger internal cache, by default, will use
>   the larger of either:
>
> 50% of (RAM - 1 GB), or 256 MB. For example, on a system with a total
>   of 4GB of RAM the WiredTiger cache will use 1.5GB of RAM (0.5 * (4 GB
>   - 1 GB) = 1.5 GB). Conversely, a system with a total of 1.25 GB of RAM will allocate 256 MB to the WiredTiger cache because that is more than
>   half of the total RAM minus one gigabyte (0.5 * (1.25 GB - 1 GB) = 128
>   MB < 256 MB).

Comment: As per MongoDB documentation the percentage is 50%. Instead of 60% RAM minus 1GB.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It must have been updated on the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your working set should stay in memory to achieve good performance. Otherwise many random disk IO’s will occur.

The working set for a MongoDB database is the portion of your data that clients access most often. You can estimate size of the working set, using

> db.runCommand( { serverStatus: 1, workingSet: 1 } )

At SO level. Look at the number or rate of page faults and other MMS gauges to detect when you need more RAM.

If page faults are infrequent, your working set fits in RAM. If fault rates rise higher than that, you risk performance degradation.

One area to watch specifically in managing the size of your working set is index access patterns. If you are inserting into indexes at random locations (as would happen with id’s that are randomly generated by hashes), you will continually be updating the whole index. If instead you are able to create your id’s in approximately ascending order (for example, day concatenated with a random id), all the updates will occur at the right side of the b-tree and the working set size for index pages will be much smaller.

Source: [MongoDb FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/)

Comment: page faults occur frequently when your working set moves, it doesn't mean your working set does not fit into RAM it just means your data is being paged in

Comment: A better way of putting it is to say that if you get frequent page faults when re-running the same queries on the same wokring set then it could be evidence that your working set does not fit in RAM